# Spring MVC: Advanced annotation based mapping

Tags: java, spring-mvc, annotations, url-routing

I am looking for a way to have complex URL mappings that would depend on the content of the database. For instance I show two URL mappings:

```
    /{category}/
    /{category}/{slug}/{id}
```

Categories can be for instance:

```
    apples, pears, lemons -> resolve to FruitListController, 
    beans, onions, potatoes -> resolve to VegetableListController.
```

- Note that those categories are stored in database and might be changed.

If I have in addition the slug and id, both of them must be checked against the database if they exist.

Can I somehow write some kind "Category handler", which would return the corresponding Category and associated Controller?

Obviously this is a problem of translating **URL -> Request**. Also, is there a way to generate backwards **Request -> URL** in similar way? I would like something like in templates:

```
  <c:foreach="apples as apple"
       <a href="${link AppleController:defaultView, ID = apple.id}">${apple.name}</a>
  </c:foreach>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [WebArgumentResolvers](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/support/WebArgumentResolver.html).  They have access to the [WebRequest](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/NativeWebRequest.html) to see your URL.  The resolvers can do your database lookups.  The FruitWebArgumentResolver could return a Fruit or return UNRESOLVED.  The VegetableArgumentResolver could return a Vegetable or return UNRESOLVED.  After the argument is resolved, the handler adapter can map to the RequestMapping that takes the specific type as an argument.  For example,

```
@RequestMapping("/{catagory}/{slug}")
public void fruitSlugList(Fruit fruit, @PathVariable("slug") String slug){
```

To see an example of this, I have a blog post here that uses the same type of mechanism:
http://www.adamweigold.com/2012/01/using-multpartrequestresolvers-with.html

Comment: Thanks for the solution, even though I am not sure how the blog post is connected to my problem. Is it possible in this way to define even optional arguments? I keep also thinking about generating the URL for given Control:view - does it provide some tools to generate them?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about "generating the URL".  As far as optional arguments, if they are RequestParams, those can be optional.

The blog post just shows an example of an ArgumentResolver being used.

If the solution is good, please accept the answer (check mark).